# What's the point of seduce in crusader kings 2? What can you do with it?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I can seduce women and sometimes have children with them. Can you do anything with the children? Like adopt them? Is there anything you can do after seduction gameplay wise or is it just a way to get opinion?

Comment: If you are a woman the children are of your dynasty, so it can be a good way to get some nice genetic traits...

Comment: @SMeznaric thanks good point. I'm mostly asking as a male character. But I see that being really useful. You should put it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several very useful things you can do with seduce:

- If you are female, you can increase the number of children you have and select your mating partners
- Same goes if you are male, you can increase the number of children, but you will gain a negative opinion modifier with all your other children
- Finally, you can target female rulers. If you acknowledge the child as yours once they are born, they will inherit the ruler's claims, which you can then press and increase your realm size

Answer (score 2):

When a bastard is born, an event MAY occur for a father to acknowledge the baby. It gives you an opinion penalty (cheated your wife) and a child is considered your own. Later you can legitimize your bastards.

Why is it useful? Right now my ruler is about 30 and has no children. Something goes wrong between him and his wife. So going seducing some women (with good genetic traits) is a way to continue my bloodline)

Comment: Is there a way to get any additional benefits such as inheriting the mother's claims or his other father's titles?

Comment: @Harry you may be lucky to inherit mother's claims and titles if this child is somewhere on top of the ladder - only 2nd and 3rd child get a claim and only the 1st inherits. I wouldn't hope for that if that woman already had a lot of kids. There is no way to compromise woman's real husband claims and titles - this child doesn't count as his own.

Answer (score 1):

It can increase your plot power also if the women/men you’re seducing have high intrigue stats. An example would be in my Venice play through. As the Doge I seduce every woman I can find in my rival patricians’ courts which makes assassinating them a breeze. This keeps my dynasty in charge of the republic with minimal campaign funds.